# By chance I bought the expensive "Caffé New York Espresso Italiano" and we are thrilled

Tags: beans

By absolute coincidence I bought [these coffee beans](https://www.galaxus.ch/de/s7/product/caffe-new-york-espresso-italiano-250-g-mittlere-roestung-kaffeebohnen-6648673?supplier=406802). [Other products](https://www.galaxus.ch/de/brand/caffe-new-york-20046) by the same vendor.

[image]

Actually, these beans are too expensive, I buy in the discount store much larger packs for the same price.

But he was absolutely fantastic, several guests have praised the good coffee.

With a web search I found no official website of this coffee manufacturer and would like to learn more why they are so good. Can anyone give factual reasons why this coffee tastes so good?

Are there similar beans, possibly a little cheaper?

What could be the magic behind these beans?

Comment: Do you have any more information? Does the package have the roast date on it by any chance, or maybe an expiration date from which we might derive that the coffee was roasted relatively recently compared to the bulk beans? Can you tell how the roast level (light vs dark roast) compares to the beans you usually have? Are the beans you usually have 100% arabica? These are just some factors that I could think of, I think we're going to need some more information to pin it down definitively, linking the coffee you usually have would also help.

Comment: It is natural to ask about what factors in to success in making good coffee, but this Question reads more like a product promotion than a well researched attempt.  Not only is the packaging disposed of, some basic aspects of how the coffee was prepared are omitted.  I have given a down vote.

Comment: "Can anyone give factual reasons why this coffee tastes so good?" Who says these beans taste good? What do you mean by good? They might taste good to you because that's the kind of taste you expect from Italian espresso, but if you ask a group of Q-Graders (professional coffee tasters) they would all say that the coffee is too bitter, unbalanced, and has no origin characteristics. What kind of coffee do you drink and like? What are you looking for in a cup of coffee?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer about that specific bag of magic beans but I can offer tips for finding coffee beans you love.

My tips on what to look for:

- Roasters who roast in small batches, taking the time to filter out defects from the raw beans and adjust the roasting time for each batch.
- Roasters who source great beans, esp. single source beans from identified farms. Those are likely to be available only seasonally and in modest quantities.
- Bags of beans that are labelled with the roast date or at least a "best by" date that's predictably 2-3 months after roast.
- Online stores of these small roasters, or retail outlets like small coffee shops and farmers' markets where you can taste coffee samples or buy a cup before buying a bag of beans.

(All this is the opposite of large roasters and grocery stores who prioritize cost. They blend cheaper beans from various sources then roast, warehouse, and ship in bulk. AIUI, grocery stores generally don't treat coffee like fresh food.)

Now watch James Hoffmann's guide to buying great coffee. He covers freshness, whole vs. pre-ground beans, traceable coffee sources as a quality clue, seasonality, places to buy coffee, roast levels, and decoding tasting notes:
https://youtu.be/O9YnLFrM7Fs